# How to best structure a TTL for elements in an array in a nosql database

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

Currently my database structure contains a user collection with documents that contain an array with elements that become irrelevant after about 2 months, what would be the best way to create this in a nosql database, as I've only seen using TTL to expire data for documents rather than elements within a document. 
I am not sure this is possible, but would like to know what alternatives people have used. I considered making each of the array elements their own documents, and storing an array that had references to each document, that way I could use TTL on the documents that corresponded to the array elements, but since TTL deletes the documents silently, I would then have invalid references in the array. I am still exploring which nosql database to go with, so suggestions on possible databases with functionality that could solve this issue.

Thanks for all the help!